A h2 title overlaps with the text under it when the h2 title wrap
How it looks when title isn't wrapping(all good)
When the screen is thinner and the title wraps
As you can see it clashes with the h3 title ("S2")
I am quite new to coding, currently learning. There should be a way to make the h3 maintain distance related to the lower part of the text above instead of staying the same distance in relation to the original margin.
I could just create a mediaquery for that screen width but I feel like there should a better solution.
Here is the relevant html snippet:
       <h1>Las 8 Funciones</h1>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <section class="caja funciones percepcion">
                <h2> Funciones de percepción</h2>
        
                <article>
                    <div class="funcion sensorial extrovertida">
                        
                            <h3>Se</h3>
                            <p>- Principales representantes: ESFP/ESTP  (Notable en: ISFP/ISTP)</p>
                            <p>- Descripción: Se concentra en las experiencias y sensaciones del mundo físico presente. Es muy consciente de su entorno y busca la acción y la aventura. </p>
                            <p>- Foco: 5 sentidos y tiempo presente</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(min-width:)" srcset="">
                        <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/53794043780_9f18208005_m.jpg" width="239" height="240" alt="muchacho haciendo truco de skateboard">
                    </picture>
                </article>

Here is the relevant CSS:
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1{
   font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2{
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   height: 3rem;
   width: 100%;
}

h3{
   font-size: 2.2rem;
   width:50%;
}

p{
   font-size: 1.7rem;
}
.contenedor{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.caja{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   border: solid 0.2rem red;
   margin: 0.5rem;
   padding: 1rem;
}

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1{
   font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2{
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   height: 3rem;
   width: 100%;
}

h3{
   font-size: 2.2rem;
   width:50%;
}

p{
   font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.contenedor{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.caja{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   border: solid 0.2rem red;
   margin: 0.5rem;
   padding: 1rem;
}

I tried playing with the margin but I noticed that the margin doesn't wrap along the text, the margin always begins from the original unwrapped content even when the content is wrapped

This is a CSS issue, so you'll need to isolate the CSS that applies to the H2 and the elements around it. Looks like you might be using positioning on the H2 or the elements around it, which is a bad idea.

Please edit your post to include the relevant CSS as well.

I'm guessing you are declaring a height for the H2 and it is overflowing its container.

@BrettDonald , done. Added the relevant CSS

@TimR oops, it was exactly that. I don't even remember why I added that height there in the first place. Removing that height solved the problem. Thank you!

@ralph.m the culprit was that I added height to h2 (I don't even remember why I did that in the first place). Removing the height fixed it
